# Apt reports multiple checksum mismatches

Tags: debian, apt

When trying to update my current Debian installation I get multiple errors of the following format:

```
Err:882 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 libgconf-2-4 amd64 3.2.6-7+b1                                                                                                        
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:54489767b897fa0d074a8f35faeb96612acff26ced53e442ed4c236693e8f8df
   - MD5Sum:5171d9b4b557120e4b3366b1d0a36ada [weak]
   - Filesize:427624 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:bd861be93497185846d897c7c85d469d1665a57daf70656b106e51007dfab180
   - MD5Sum:5171d9b4b557120e4b3366b1d0a36ada [weak]
   - Filesize:427624 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Sun, 13 Mar 2022 09:40:49 +0000
Get:883 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 gdbm-l10n all 1.23-1 [99.4 kB]                                                                                                       
Get:884 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 gimp-data all 2.10.30-1 [14.1 MB]                                                                                                    
Err:884 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 gimp-data all 2.10.30-1                                                                                                              
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:8305fd85027f2c50c167c5ec9317b2354ef0fd891a257b0d31672c1586e47fd2
   - MD5Sum:06dcccaeaad7f4a7d9e6cc1b8cf1d120 [weak]
   - Filesize:14054976 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:51606302f48205ca7a04b27065ebde2230f88ce8a2108d61ba7b999c0269f89f
   - MD5Sum:06dcccaeaad7f4a7d9e6cc1b8cf1d120 [weak]
   - Filesize:14054976 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Tue, 28 Dec 2021 04:26:35 +0000
```

My current sources list contains the following

```
deb http://ftp.no.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.no.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
```

but I tried different mirrors to no avail.

Also, I checked the checksums returned by `apt-get --print-uris download` and manually confirmed them, as suggested by [a-b](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/251756/a-b) in the comments, and the returned checksum matches the expected ones (i.e. 54489767b897fa0d074a8f35faeb96612acff26ced53e442ed4c236693e8f8df for libgconf-2-4).

Comment: Try to download it by hand (`apt-get --print-uris download libgconf-2-4/sid` then curl or wget), and use sha256sum by hand to see if the same problem happens. You could change mirror to see if there's a difference.

Comment: Thanks @A.B So I tried your suggestions and both the shown checksum and the one downloaded manually match. Switching mirror doesn't help, as mentioned above.

Comment: Now I'm really puzzled. Btw, the expected checksum is the correct one: it should start with 544... I'm not sure what checksum you got. You should be precise.

Comment: Yes, the one starting with 544 @A.B. Is it possible that `apt` is either compromised or broken here?

Comment: No idea. It's still unclear if apt's download failed somehow or the checksum got the wrong result with a correct download.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the problem seems to be non-deterministic. I created a snapshot of the system and with each try some packages fail, but different set each time.

Comment: @A.B Turns out I unintentionally omitted a crucial piece of information ‒ the system runs as VirtualBox (6.1.34-dfsg-3) guest on Debian Sid host. Later I noticed that the system (and other guests) became quite unstable. After some investigation, it turned out that this seems to be related to 5.18.2-1 kernel on host. Switching to 5.17.11-1 seems to resolve the issue, as far as I can tell. Weird... Not even sure where and how to report this.